# Counting historical records at key dates

Tags: sql, oracle

We have two tables in our data warehouse: c_customers and h_customers, containing current and historical customer records.

Both tables have a 'DWH_FROM' and 'DWH_TO' columns, with all records in c_customers having 'DWH_TO' = null.

PK for c_customers is CUST_NR, whereas for h_customers it's CUST_NR, DWH_FROM and DWH_TO.

When customer data changes, a new record is inserted into c_customers with a blank DWH_TO value, whereas the old one is moved to h_customers with DWH_TO containing the date the change took place.

How can I get a list of how many customers (distinct CUST_NR) had STATUS = 'Active' as of the first of every month of 2016, alternatively for every date in 2016?

Ideal output would be something like:

```
Date       | Count
-----------+------
01.01.2016 | 22385
01.02.2016 | 23187
...        |
01.12.2016 | 25109
```

I've come as far as generating a dataset with:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CUST_NR,
             STATUS,
             DWH_FROM,
             DWH_TO
      FROM C_CUSTOMER C
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CUST_NR,
             STATUS,
             DWH_FROM,
             DWH_TO
      FROM H_CUSTOMER H
     );
```

...but I'm not really sure how to count customers as of a certain date, for multiple dates.

Comment: Would you like to share what have you done so far, sample data of input tables, etc.?

Comment: Is it fair to assume that a specific customer will **not** have overlapping intervals in the historical table? They may appear more than once, but not more than once *on the same date*? (And no overlap with their current record - so they won't be in both tables on the same date?)

Comment: c_customer always contains the last known record of customer data.
h_customer contains historical data which has been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force method.  You can do this for one date by doing:

```
select c.cnt + h.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from c_customer c
      where date '2016-01-01' <= c.dw_to
     ) c cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from h_customer c
      where date '2016-01-01' between c.dw_to and c.dw_from
     ) h;
```

You can adapt this using correlated subqueries:

```
select d.dte,
       ( (select count(*) as cnt
          from c_customer c
          where date d.dte <= c.dw_to
         ) +
         (select count(*) as cnt
          from h_customer c
          where date d.dte between c.dw_to and c.dw_from
         )
        ) as cnt 
from (select date '2016-01-01' as dte from dual union all
      select date '2016-02-01' as dte from dual union all
      select date '2016-03-01' as dte from dual union all
      . . . 
     ) d;
```

This isn't the only way to solve this problem.  But for a handful of dates, it should be fine in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a real problem for this question indeed. If you have a dates table you can do a full join on it and use some query as following:

```
WITH dates AS 
(SELECT '2016-01-01' AS dateid
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-05-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-06-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-07-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-09-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-11-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-12-01'
)

,c_cust AS 
    (SELECT 1 AS CustNr, 'a' AS name, '2014-01-01' AS DWH_FROM, NULL AS DWH_TO
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,'b', '2015-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,'c', '2016-01-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 5,'e', '2016-04-01', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 6,'f', '2016-06-01', NULL
    )

, h_cust AS 
    (SELECT 10 AS CustNr, 'j' AS name, '2010-01-01' AS DWH_FROM, '2010-12-31' AS DWH_TO
    UNION ALL SELECT 12,'k', '2015-01-01', '2016-12-31'
    UNION ALL SELECT 15,'m', '2016-01-01', '2016-06-31'
    UNION ALL SELECT 20,'p', '2014-01-01', '2016-03-31'
    UNION ALL SELECT 26,'r', '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'
    )
,all_cust AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM c_cust c
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM h_cust h
)

SELECT d.dateid, COUNT(*) AS ActiveUsers
FROM all_cust c
,dates d
WHERE d.dateid > c.DWH_FROM AND d.dateid < ISNULL(c.DWH_TO, '9999-12-31')
GROUP BY d.dateid
```

You get the result:

```
dateid  ActiveUsers
2016-01-01  4
2016-02-01  6
2016-03-01  6
2016-04-01  5
2016-05-01  6
2016-06-01  6
2016-07-01  6
2016-08-01  6
2016-09-01  6
2016-10-01  6
2016-11-01  6
2016-12-01  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way of solving this problem.

Somewhere, somehow you will need to create all the dates needed for the report (the first of the month for every month in 2016). I do this in a hierarchical (sub)query which I named `mth` in the solution.

In the code below I create test data in a `with` clause; that data is not part of the solution (it should be removed before using against your actual tables). I didn't use exactly your table names - and I only created the columns that are relevant to this exercise.

Putting column names in subquery declarations like I did in the `with` clause was a new feature in Oracle 11.2; if you are using an older version, you will need to move the column names into each subquery definition. This is a trivial change, if needed.

The strategy is to join the "months" or "calendar" table (the one containing the 12 first-of-month dates) to each of the "current" and "historical" customer tables, using the appropriate join condition for each. Collect the results with `UNION ALL` (which is possible, since in each join all we need to retain is the "calendar" date, first-of-month, whenever there is a match to a row in either customer table). Then it's a simple matter of grouping by date and counting.

```
with
    curr_cust ( custnr, dwh_from ) as ( 
    select 101, date '2013-10-15' from dual union all
    select 102, date '2016-03-11' from dual union all
    select 105, date '2015-04-02' from dual union all
    select 113, date '2016-12-15' from dual
    ),
    hist_cust ( custnr, dwh_from, dwh_to ) as (
      select 100, date '2014-12-01', date '2015-12-20' from dual union all
      select 102, date '2015-11-15', date '2016-02-08' from dual union all
      select 108, date '2016-03-01', date '2016-08-03' from dual union all
      select 108, date '2016-10-15', date '2016-12-15' from dual
    ),
    mth ( dt ) as (
      select add_months(date '2016-01-01', level - 1) from   dual
      connect by level <= 12
    )
select   to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as dt, count(*) as cust_count
from     ( select dt
             from mth m join curr_cust c on m.dt >= c.dwh_from
           union all
           select dt
             from mth m join hist_cust h on m.dt between h.dwh_from and h.dwh_to
         )
group by dt
order by dt   --  if needed
;
```

**Output** (with the test data included in the query):

```
DT         CUST_COUNT
---------- ----------
2016-01-01          3
2016-02-01          3
2016-03-01          3
2016-04-01          4
2016-05-01          4
2016-06-01          4
2016-07-01          4
2016-08-01          4
2016-09-01          3
2016-10-01          3
2016-11-01          4
2016-12-01          4

12 rows selected.
```